# Need to add @color attribute with color name in each nested 'dn' element under the 'dyn'

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need to add @color attribute with color name in each nested 'dn' element if position is even, @color attribute to the second, fourth, sixth etc. dn child of each level and as well as dn element following-sibling of dn element
I try with position function but unable to get solution
Please look into this and Thanks in advance

**Input XML file:**

```
<dyn>
    <dn></dn>
    <dn></dn>
    <dn>
        <dn></dn>
        <dn></dn>
        <dn>
            <dn></dn>
            <dn></dn>
            <dn></dn>
        </dn>
    </dn>
</dyn>
```

**XSLT file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="dyn">
        <dyn>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="following::dn/position() mod 2 = 0">
                <dn>
             <xsl:attribute name="color">
                 <xsl:value-of select="'red'"/>
             </xsl:attribute>
                </dn>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise/>
        </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        
        </dyn>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
<dyn>
<dn></dn>
<dn color="red"></dn>
<dn>
<dn></dn>
<dn color="red">
</dn>
<dn>
<dn color="red"></dn>
<dn></dn>
<dn color="red"></dn>
<dn>
</dn></dn>
</dn>
</dyn>
```

Comment: Can you indent the result/expected output sample? Does `position is even` mean you want to to add the `color` attribute to the second, fourth, sixth etc. `dn` child of each level?

Comment: Yes, I want to add color attribute to the second, fourth, sixth etc. dn child of each level

Comment: Yes, I want to add color attribute to the second, fourth, sixth etc. dn child of each level and as well as dn following-sibling.
<dyn>
<dn></dn>
<dn color="red"></dn>
<dn>
<dn></dn>
<dn color="red"></dn>
</dn>
</dyn>

Comment: See whether the answer helps. If not, edit your question to explain and show in a well-formatted and indented way the result you need.

Comment: Use the "Edit" feature to edit the question and show the needed result there as a formatted code sample, don't use comments for that.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, Please see my expected output, now I have edited as indent

Comment: For the first two levels the second `dn` has a `color="red"` attribute in your output sample, for the third level suddenly it changes to the first and third `dn` child havind the `color="red"` attribute. Based on that, I still don't understand the criteria as to when to add the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your verbal description sounds as if you want

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dn[position() mod 2 = 0]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="color">red</xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

This gives the output

```
<dyn>
    <dn/>
    <dn color="red"/>
    <dn>
        <dn/>
        <dn color="red"/>
        <dn>
            <dn/>
            <dn color="red"/>
            <dn/>
        </dn>
    </dn>
</dyn>
```

which has the right attributes for the first two levels but on the third level it gives the second `dn` child that `color="red"` attribute while your wanted output, for reasons I have so far not understood, there adds the attribute to the first and third `dn` child.